# Integer index-able RAII container for non-copyable type

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Is there a standard container that has the same general API as `vector<T>` but that populates new locations via direct default construction?

---

*Background:*

I have a type that disallows copying but has a default constructor and what I really want to do is this:

```
vector<NoCopy> bag(some_size);

// use bag[i]'s

return; // bag & contents get correctly cleaned up.
```

However, this doesn't work because `vector<T>(int)` is implemented in terms of default constructing an object and then copying it into each of the new locations.

---

Edit: Not C++0xB (a.k.a. C++11)

Comment: How about the `std::array` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: He didn't ask for C++11, though.

Comment: He didn't specifically ask for C++98 either.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to upgrade to a C++11-compliant Standard Library implementation.

In C++11, the `vector(size_type)` constructor default constructs N elements into the container.  It neither copies nor moves any elements.

Visual C++ 2010 does not support this C++11 feature; I believe the Visual C++ 11 Developer Preview does correctly support it though.  I do not know whether recent versions of libstdc++ support this; I would suspect that libc++ does.

Comment: There is no `std::vector<T>(size_type)` constructor. There is a `std::vector<T>(size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator())` constructor, which takes a value. It can be a default-constructed object or something you provide. Either way, it *copies* from this value `n` times.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  In C++98, yes.  In C++11, there is a new constructor, `vector(size_type)`, which default constructs the elements directly into the container.  An implementation is not permitted to copy or move any elements during the construction.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container.html), new in Boost 1.48, has a `boost::container::vector` which provides this feature. It's C++03 conforming, with [select C++11 features](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/Cpp11_conformance.html).

Well, there is one C++03 that `boost::container::vector` doesn't conform with: `vector<bool>` is actually a `vector` of `bool`s. Though I imagine most people would count that as a *benefit*.

Answer (score 2):

Call it a workaround, but when I need containers of NoCopy types I usually use boost::ptr_vector or std::vector< shared_ptr >.

Obviously, it's slightly more expensive, but luckily for me that has not been a problem for me yet.

The good thing about boost::ptr_vector is that it does [automatic dereferencing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#indirected-interface) on some accesses. [Check out the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: Workaround for sure. The ugly with that is that I then have to go in and populate the thing. :(

Comment: @BCS - Yes, you are correct. Pre-populationg a noncopyable type into such a container can be annoying.