# When does it make sense to use unique_ptr with STL containers? (C++11)

Tags: c++, coding-style, stl, c++11, unique-ptr

A container of `unique_ptr` seems to make little sense: you cannot use it with initializer lists and I failed to iterate through the container (workarounds below). Am I misunderstanding something? Or when does it make sense to use `unique_ptr` and STL containers?

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Base { void go() { }  virtual ~Base() { } }; 
// virtual ~Base() = default; gives
// "declared virtual cannot be defaulted in the class body" why?

class Derived : public Base { };

int main() {

  //vector<unique_ptr<Base>> v1 = { new Derived, new Derived, new Derived };
  //vector<shared_ptr<Base>> v2 = { new Derived, new Derived, new Derived };
  vector<Base*> v3 = { new Derived, new Derived, new Derived };
  vector<shared_ptr<Base>> v4(v3.begin(), v3.end());
  vector<unique_ptr<Base>> v5(v3.begin(), v3.end());

  for (auto i : v5) { // works with v4
    i->go();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

The following questions helped me find these workarounds:

- [How to initialize a container of noncopyable with initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6804216/341970)
- [Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8468774/341970)
- [when I need containers of NoCopy types I usually use `boost::ptr_vector` or `std::vector<shared_ptr>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331474/341970)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for (auto i : v5) {
  i->go();
}
```

Should be

```
for (auto& i : v5) { // note 'auto&'
  i->go();
}
```

Else you'll try to copy the current element.

Also, you can't use an initializer list like that, because the constructors of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are marked `explicit`. You need to do something like this:

```
#include <iterator> // make_move_iterator, begin, end

template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(){ // naive implementation
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T());
}

std::unique_ptr<Base> v1_init_arr[] = {
    make_unique<Derived>(), make_unique<Derived>(), make_unique<Derived>()
};

// these two are only for clarity
auto first = std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(v1_init_arr));
auto last = std::make_move_iterator(std::end(v1_init_arr));
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v1(first, last);

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> v2 = {
    std::make_shared<Derived>(),
    std::make_shared<Derived>(),
    std::make_shared<Derived>()
};
```

And this is a Good Thing™, because otherwise you might leak memory (if one of the later constructors throws, the former ones aren't yet bound to the smart pointers). The tip-toeing for the `unique_ptr` is necessary, because initializer lists copy their arguments, and since `unique_ptr`s aren't copyable, you'd get a problem.

---

That said, I use a `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<LoaderBase>>` for a dictionary of loaders in one of my projects.

Comment: `vector<unique_ptr<Base>> v1 = { make_unique<Derived>(), make_unique<Derived>(), make_unique<Derived>() };` <-- Did you test that?

Comment: As @Benjamin alludes to, initializer lists make copies by definition, so they cannot be used with move-only objects.

Comment: @Benjamin: Admittedly, no, since I currently have no compiler available that supports initializer lists like that. I don't see what problem could crop up though?

Comment: @Xeo: The problem is that initializer lists are immutable.

Comment: You can do it with an array though: `unique_ptr<Base> v1[] = { make_unique<Derived>(), make_unique<Derived>(), make_unique<Derived>() };`

Comment: @Benjamin: Damn, [I actually knew that it won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8468774/500104), but I forgot again! :( Editing my answer right now.

Comment: @Benjamin: Yep, and then move the things into the vector. See the edited answer. :)

Comment: @Xeo The syntax for v1 in the example code is hideous :( I was waiting for the C++Ox a lot but I might as well stick with C++98 and use the old syntax for constructing, it is just as hideous... I am missing the big breakthrough.

Comment: @Benjamin : It will work with `std::array<>` as well, since it's still just aggregate initialization. :-]

Comment: @Ali: The big breakthrough is that you will have no memory leaks in the face of exceptions, since every pointer will be bound to a managing object before the next one is constructed. It doesn't matter if it looks hideous or convoluted, what matters is the safety.

Comment: @Xeo Yes, I get the safety part. I was expecting the syntax getting simpler with the extended initializer lists, hence my disappointment.

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr` makes sense in STL containers when the container holds objects that can't be copied.  Or if it's costly or simply incorrect to copy them.

You get the same functionality as your

```
vector<Base*> v3 = { new Derived, new Derived, new Derived };
```

But without the memory leaks that `v3` is inviting.

Comment: Or when you need polymorphic behavior.

Comment: You can put uncopyable objects (such as `unique_ptr`) into C++11 containers; although some containers require that they are movable.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can iterate though the container without issues using `std::unique_ptr<T>` ... you just either need to access a reference (i.e., not a copy) of the unique pointer, or you need to actually use an iterator-type with the container.  In your case that would be something like `vector<unique_ptr<Base>>::iterator` or `vector<unique_ptr<Base>>::const_iterator`.