# C++ - polymorphism: initialization of a container class with derived classes

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, initializer-list, variadic-functions

I have a question regarding polymorphism and *maybe* other techniques. Consider the following scheme:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{ };

struct Derived : Base
{ };

class group
{
    private:
        vector< unique_ptr<Base> > V;
    public:
        group( /* what to put here? */ )
        : V( /* again: how to construct V? */ )
        { }
}
```

Here, I have three classes: a base class, called `Base`; a derived class, called `Derived`; and a last class, `group`, that would act as a wrapper to hold `Base` pointers. But I'd like to achieve the following:

- **Use move semantics**. There should be no copies involved. The caller should be able to give the constructor several *temporaries*, as the constructor would steal them:

  ```
  group my_wonderful_group( Base( /* parameters */ ) , Derived ( /* ... */ ) , Derived ( /* ... */ ) );
  ```
- **Initialize `V` in the initialization list**. That way, `V` could be *const*-qualified (despite all the other benefits initializing member objects in initialization lists carries).

I've tried several things, but they either do not seem appropiate, or are simply conceptually far from my goals:

- `initializer_list`s' elements are **non-movable**; `unique_ptr`s are **movable-only**.
- **Variadic templates** do not seem capable to fit the goal of making `V` *const*. As `initializer_list`s can't hold objects of different types (just like `vector`s), I first thought about them, but, how? After reading many examples, I still can't figure out how to make a *variadic template constructor*, or even if it's possible to do so without a workaround (i.e.: creating some *init()* function that takes a `Base`, a `Derived`,... and plays with it).
- Create a function that returns `unique_ptr<Base>` and that forwards its arguments to the constructor of `Derived`, thus acting as an user-friendly wrapper to the `group` class. This does, however, make little sense, as I illustrate with the code attached below.

This is what I have:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    string s;
    Base(Base && b) : s(move(b.s)) { }
    Base(const string & S) : s( S ) { }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived(const string & S) : Base( S ) { }
};

unique_ptr<Base>
BASE ( const string & S )
{
    return unique_ptr<Base>( new Base(S) );
}

unique_ptr<Base>
DERIVED ( const string & S )
{
    return unique_ptr<Base>( new Derived(S) );
}

class C
{
    private:
        vector< unique_ptr<Base> > V;
    public:
        template<typename ... T>
            C
            ( T ... t ) : V({ t... })
            { }

        void
            print
            ( void )
            {
                for ( const auto & x : this->V )
                    cout << x->s << endl;
            }
            ;
};


int main(void)
{
    C c( BASE("hola") , DERIVED("der1") , DERIVED("bor3") );
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

It complains, however, about the usage of the [deleted] copy constructor of `unique_ptr` being called, when the argument pack in the constructor of `group` is expanded and comma-separated put into the `initializer_list` that *would* be used to initialize `V`.

I guess that my question goes down to a `vector`, and, in fact, could be applied to one: `vector<unique_ptr<Base>>( /* initialize with derived classes */ )`. I think this must have been solved before, as polymorphism is basic C++, and holding objects of derived classes seems a very common usage of it. As a note, I use `g++ 4.8.1`.

Thanks in advance. Best regards,
Kalrish

P.S.: I've just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764591/when-does-it-make-sense-to-use-unique-ptr-with-stl-containers-c11) which seems to partly cover my problem.

Comment: did you consider the use of Boost.Variant (www.boost.org/libs/variant) ? Because it really seems to match exactly what you want to achieve with your group class.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type to solve the vector initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should solve all your issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    string s;
    Base(const Base& b) = delete;
    Base(Base && b) : s(move(b.s)) { }
    Base(const string & S) : s( S ) { }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived(const string & S) : Base( S ) { }
};

#if 1 // not in C++11
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Ts&&...args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Ts>(args)...});
}
#endif

// vector<move_only> cannot be construct from initializer list :-/
// Use this work around
template <typename Base, typename ... Ts>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> make_vector_of_unique(Ts&&... ts)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> init[] = {make_unique<Ts>(std::forward<Ts>(ts))...};
    return std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> {
        std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(init)),
        std::make_move_iterator(std::end(init))};
}

class C
{
private:
    const std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Base> > V;
public:
    template<typename ... Ts>
    C(Ts&& ... t) : V(make_vector_of_unique<Base>(std::forward<Ts>(t)...))
    {}

    void print()
    {
        for (const auto & x : this->V)
            std::cout << x->s << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c( Base("hola") , Derived("der1") , Derived("bor3") );
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```